# linking library class to an extended class and baseclass

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, hyperlink, superclass

The use of library classes confuses me once again.
I have the following situation:

```
package com.op_pad.pages
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Martino Wullems
 */
public class Page extends MovieClip 
{
    public var currentPage:String = ""; //help page label
    public var testvar:int = 0;
    var helpPage:HelpPage;

    public function Page(PAGENAME:String = null):void {

        //tweening etc
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

        trace("currentPage: " + currentPage);
        trace("testvar: " + testvar);
    }

    private function onStage(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

        trace("on stgae called");

        try { terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback, false, null, true) } catch (e) {  };
        try{homebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome, false, 0, true)}catch (e) { };
        try { stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true) } catch (e) { trace("back button fail"); };
        try { help.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showHelpPage, false, 0, true) } catch (e) { trace("help not found") };
    }

    public function addListeners():void {

        //try{terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback, false, null, true)}catch(e){};
        //try{homebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goHome, false, 0, true)}catch (e) { };
        //try{stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, false, 0, true)}catch (e) {trace("back button fail"); };
    }

    public function goback(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        try { MovieClip(parent).loading = false } catch (e) { trace("loading boolean not existent");}
        MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
    }

    private function goHome(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        try { MovieClip(parent).loading = false } catch (e) { trace("loading boolean not existent");}
        MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
    }

    private function showHelpPage(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        helpPage = new HelpPage();
        addChild(helpPage);
        helpPage.gotoAndStop(currentPage);

        trace("help page called, currentPage: " + currentPage);
    }

    private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {   
        //when keyboard back is pressed
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            goback(null);
        }
    }   
}   
}
```

Sloppy code, still needs cleaning up.

A child class that inherits the Page class

```
package
{
import com.op_pad.pages.Page;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Martino Wullems
 */
public class FavorietenPage extends Page
{

    public function FavorietenPage():void
    {
        trace("favorietenpage called");

        super();
        currentPage = "favorieten";
    }   
}
}
```

"FavorietenPage" is also a library item that I want to add to the stage. I have tried several setups but cannot get it to work.

Most logical to me seems the following [library item properties]:
Class: com.op_pad.pages.FavorietenPage
BaseClass: com.op_pad.pages.Page;

I cannot put in any baseclass when using the class, so I'm forced to remove the baseclass.
When using only the class I get a whole bunch of errors don't make any sense at all, and still appear even if I comment out all the code in the Page class.

```
com\op_pad\pages\FavorietenPage.as:7: 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition com.op_pad.pages:Page.help in namespace public.

com\op_pad\pages\FavorietenPage.as:12: 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition com.op_pad.pages:Page.terug in namespace public.

com\op_pad\pages\FavorietenPage.as:21: 1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition com.op_pad.pages:Page.home in namespace public.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me at all. 
Any idea how this situation should be used?Thanks in advance

Comment: If i'm following correctly, you had a movieclip in you library called favorietenPage_mc(or a similar name), its class name was FavorietenPage, its base class was com.op_pad.FavorietenPage and that extended com.op_pad.Page?

Comment: Is Page also a library symbol? if so, I don't think you can use a library symbol as baseclass (haven't tried it though). Does it work if you set the baseclass as FavorietenPage?

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the meaning of the "class" and "base class" fields in the properties panel:

> The value of the Base Class defaults
>   to `flash.display.MovieClip`. Use this
>   default unless you are using an
>   automatically generated class that
>   uses the functionality of an external
>   class. Base Class is not synonomous
>   with extension; if you are specifying
>   a custom class that itself extends
>   another class, it is not necessary to
>   specify this superclass as the Base
>   Class. In this situation, the default
>   of `flash.display.MovieClip` is
>   sufficient. If, however, you wanted
>   two symbols, RedFish and BlueFish, to
>   function identically but have
>   different skins, you could use the
>   authoring tool to create different
>   appearances, then set their Base Class
>   to Fish and use a Fish class in an
>   external Fish.as file to provide the
>   functionality for both fish.

(from the [Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/external_files_as3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0))